# Cocoa: Get Notified after Text Cell (NSTextField) is Edited & Start Editing Text Cell after Adding it in NSTableView in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, swift4

I have made a simple demo using TableView here: https://github.com/deadcoder0904/TableViewDemo

I have used [Defaults](https://github.com/sindresorhus/Defaults) module as a dependency

My project looks like

[image: follow your dreams]

All the code is in `ViewController.swift` as follows -

```
import Cocoa
import Defaults

extension Defaults.Keys {
    static let dreams = Defaults.Key<Array<String>>("dreams", default: [
        "Hit the gym",
        "Run daily",
        "Become a millionaire",
        "Become a better programmer",
        "Achieve your dreams"
        ])
}

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var table: NSTableView!
    var dreams = defaults[.dreams]
    var selectedRow:Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        table.dataSource = self
        table.delegate = self
    }

    override var acceptsFirstResponder : Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func keyDown(with theEvent: NSEvent) {
        if theEvent.keyCode == 51 {
            removeDream()
        }
    }

    func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        let table = notification.object as! NSTableView
        selectedRow = table.selectedRow
    }

    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return dreams.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        let dream = table.makeView(withIdentifier: tableColumn!.identifier, owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
        dream.textField?.stringValue = dreams[row]

        return dream
    }

    @IBAction func addTableRow(_ sender: Any) {
        addNewDream()
    }

    @IBAction func removeTableRow(_ sender: Any) {
        removeDream()
    }

    func addNewDream() {
        dreams.append("Double Click or Press Enter to Add Item")
        table.beginUpdates()
        let last = dreams.count - 1
        table.insertRows(at: IndexSet(integer: last), withAnimation: .effectFade)
        table.scrollRowToVisible(last)
        table.selectRowIndexes([last], byExtendingSelection: false)
        table.endUpdates()
        saveDreams()
    }

    func removeDream() {
        if selectedRow >= dreams.count {
            selectedRow = dreams.count - 1
        }
        if selectedRow != -1 {
            dreams.remove(at: selectedRow)
            table.removeRows(at: IndexSet(integer: selectedRow), withAnimation: .effectFade)
        }
        saveDreams()
    }

    func saveDreams() {
        defaults[.dreams] = dreams
    }
}
```

I want to do 2 things -

1. Get notified after Text Cell is edited so that I can save the changed data using Defaults module
2. After adding new Data by Clicking on the plus sign it adds **Double Click or Press Enter to Add Item** but what I want is I want to add Empty String which I can do with "" but I also want it to be focused & be editable so user can start entering text in it without having to **Double Click or Press Enter**.

I also want a solution in Swift 4 & not Objective-C. How to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode Swift. How to programmatically select Cell in view-based NSTableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37194836/xcode-swift-how-to-programmatically-select-cell-in-view-based-nstableview)

Comment: No @Willeke its not a duplicate. I manage to select the last row but I want to do something else. Please read the question :)

Comment: Which question?

Comment: My question. Here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/q/52251945/6141587. What I want is I want to get notified when the Row in NSTableView is edited so I can persist its state & save it to the disk. My another question is After pressing + button how can I auto-focus on the newly added row that I can start typing in without having to press Double-Click or Press Enter like what I'm doing now. I've also made a sample Github Repo to clone.

Comment: Duplicate of [make NSTextField in NSTableCellView firstResponder()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49327072/make-nstextfield-in-nstablecellview-firstresponder).

Comment: I downloaded the Github Repo but I don't want to install Defaults.

Comment: Sure I thought instead of asking same thing twice I'd ask it once but sure I will ask only 1 question in the future. If you revert to previous commit it doesn't have Defaults. I'll take a look at the question you provided above.

Comment: Use Cocoa Bindings. This provides both *things* without adding extra code and you can even remove the table view datasource methods.

Comment: Does `editColumn(_:row:with:select:)` not make the cell focused & editable?

Comment: @vadian I checked Cocoa Bindings but couldn't find an easy article to understand it. I checked Ray Wenderlich article but as I am beginner I couldn't grasp all of it sadly. Could you provide a beginner link?

Comment: @Willeke Can you specify complete code for `editColumn(_:row:with:select:)`? I'll try to find it but it will require some time though.

Comment: @Willeke So my 2nd question worked. I used your SO link & now after pressing + it focuses on the last item & starts editing. Now I'll check the 1st one if it works.

Comment: @Willeke I tried `editColumn` but it doesn't work. Maybe I implemented it wrong. Can you check it [here](https://github.com/deadcoder0904/TableViewDemo/commit/6fe90650ae22a026a663e87997ba4e42de373fd7) ?

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me see if it works so I can upvote & accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Cocoa Bindings, it's very powerful and saves a lot of boilerplate code.

Short tutorial:

**Edit:** To take full advantage of KVC the data source must be an `NSObject` subclass with `dynamic` properties

- Create a simple class `Dream` (the `description` property is optional)

  ```
  class Dream : NSObject {
      @objc dynamic var name : String
      init(name : String) { self.name = name }
      override var description : String { return "Dream " + name }
  }
  ```
- In the view controller declare the data source array

  ```
  var dreams = [Dream]()
  ```
- and replace `var selectedRow:Int = 0` with

  ```
  @objc dynamic var selectedIndexes = IndexSet()
  ```
- Go to Interface Builder

  - Select the table view, press <kbd>⌥⌘7</kbd> to go to the Bindings Inspector.
    Bind `Selection Indexes` to `View Controller` *Model Key Path* `selectedIndexes`.
    Press <kbd>⌥⌘6</kbd> and connect the `dataSource` (by drag&drop) to the view controller ([image]) .
  - Select the text field `File 1` in `Table Cell View` in the table column. The easiest way is to <kbd>⌃⇧click</kbd> in the text field area.
    Press <kbd>⌥⌘7</kbd> and bind `Value` to `Table Cell View` *Model Key Path* `objectValue.name` (**!**)
- In the view controller populate the data source array in `viewDidLoad` ( I don't know that framework so I leave it out) and reload the table view.

  ```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      let dreamNames = ["Hit the gym", "Run daily", "Become a millionaire", "Become a better programmer", "Achieve your dreams"]
      dreams = dreamNames.map{Dream(name: $0)}
      table.reloadData()         
  }
  ```
- Delete `acceptsFirstResponder`
- Delete `tableViewSelectionDidChange`
- Delete `tableView:viewFor:row:`
- Add

  ```
  func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
      return dreams[row]
  }
  ```
- Replace `addNewDream` with

  ```
  func addNewDream() {
       let last = dreams.count
       dreams.append(Dream(name: "Double Click or Press Enter to Add Item"))
       table.insertRows(at: IndexSet(integer: last), withAnimation: .effectGap)
       table.scrollRowToVisible(last)
       table.selectRowIndexes([last], byExtendingSelection: false)

       saveDreams()
   }
  ```
- Replace `removeDream()` with

  ```
  func removeDream() {
       guard let selectedRow = selectedIndexes.first else { return }
       dreams.remove(at: selectedRow)
       table.removeRows(at: IndexSet(integer: selectedRow), withAnimation: .effectFade)

       saveDreams()
   }
  ```

To save the array when the text was edited afterwards you have to implement the delegate method `controlTextDidEndEditing(_:)`

```
override func controlTextDidEndEditing(_ obj: Notification) {
    saveDreams()
}
```

and in Interface Builder connect the `delegate` of the text field in the table view to the view controller.

Comment: Thank you very much @vadian. That works perfectly well & it reduced so much of my boilerplate. I've uploaded it [here](https://github.com/deadcoder0904/TableViewDemoUsingCocoaBindings) if anyone ever faces the same problem :) Again thank you

Comment: In the linked project `tableView(:viewFor:row:)` is still there. **Delete** it, it's redundant. The view and assigning the values is managed by Cocoa Bindings.

Comment: How to get the new text when row is changed?

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean with *new text* and *row changed* ?

Comment: I deleted it in the new commit & added `Defaults` module but one last thing remaining is after editing I can't get the new data. How do I get it?

Comment: See the last section of my answer. You need to implement the `NSTextField` delegate method

Comment: Let me explain. After you click +, you can enter new text & data gets added. But suppose I want to edit the first item & change from "Hit the gym" to "Go Skydiving", I will press Enter & change it to "Go Skydiving" & its changed. But after I close the app & re-run again I can't see it because I didn't persist it. So how will I get the "Go Skydiving" after its edited from old text (this is different from clicking plus button). Hope you understand. If not I'll be happy to provide a GIF.

Comment: I checked it out but the real problem I am having is how do I persist now with the Defaults module. Its a very small module but very helpful than built-in UserDefaults. But I can't seem to figure out how to use it when I am doing KVC. Can you take a look at it? It won't require you more than 2 mins to understand it. Here's the link https://github.com/sindresorhus/Defaults if you can help with it. Thank you for the answer. You've been really helpful in a big way :)

Comment: Honestly I don't understand the sense of those libraries. `UserDefaults` is straightforward and you can extend it very easy just for your needs. For example you can write an extension for `Dream` (about 8 lines of code). You have a few options: 1) save only the names `let dreamNames = dreams.map{$0}` and load them like described in `viewDidLoad`. 2) Adopt `Codable` to `Dream` and save the array as Property List or as JSON. 3) Adopt `NSCoding` to `Dream` and save the array as archive. I recommend the first option.

Comment: Cool I'll try it now. The library reduced a lot of code for me. I had 80 LOCs of Preferences & needed to store 5-6 properties. With that Library I reduced the code to <10 LOCs. That library is also very small <100 LOCs but why to reinvent the wheel again & again when we can just get the job done with it.

Comment: Thank you so much @vadian. The first method worked & I'll post the code on Github https://github.com/deadcoder0904/TableViewDemoUsingCocoaBindings